# Would Theresa May's end of free-movement to European Migrants be against their Human Rights?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, brexit

It has been [written](http://www.independent.ie/world-news/europe/britain/theresa-may-set-to-announce-end-of-free-movement-for-new-eu-migrants-on-the-same-day-brexit-negotiations-begin-report-35484419.html) that Theresa May plans to end the free movement of European Migrants entering the UK permanently when Article 50 has been triggered. Because this date is before Britain leaves the EU officially:

- Wouldn't it be against the Human Rights of said migrants if
  they do restrict free-movement? or are they able to restrict
  free-movement before Britain has officially left the EU?

Comment: The problem with human rights is that it is not a universally agreed upon set of rights. I might think freedom of movement is a human right, you might not, and Bob might think somewhere in the middle. On top of that there are no international laws that are binding that define a right to movement. In short, just because Wiki says its a human right doesn't mean that a nation can't restrict its borders.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg So it doesn't conflict with any policy applicable to the between UK and EU? I.e. European Convention of Human Rights or any of the sort? Or its just down to the discretion of the country restricting the freedom of movement?

Comment: @DavidGrinberg, Bradley: the problem with the framing of this question is that the general right of freedom of movement recognized by most countries is not particularly relevant to European Union freedom of movement.  That is instead a right that flows from the treaties that form the EU, and specifically concerns the right of citizens to move between member states of the EU.

Comment: Bradley: your edit improves the question somewhat, but I wonder if there's a particular human right you're interested in.  The biggest problem I can see with May's reported plans is within the framework of freedom of movement itself, not a human rights problem.  But I'm reluctant to write up an answer explaining that because it doesn't address your question as it is now posed.

Comment: i'll edit my question now, bud.

Comment: Thanks.  Also note that the reported proposal is not to end freedom of movement altogether on invoking article 50, but to make that the cutoff date for people to be able to qualify for *permanent residence.*  There will certainly have to be *some* cutoff date, after all, but permanent residence is only acquired after 5 years, so the reported proposal may even be more generous than it needs to be, depending on whether Art. 50 negotiations are extended for more than 3 years beyond the 2-year default limit.

Comment: This is a question for Law.SE since any interpretation of the answer is likely to be a misreading or complete disregarding of actual European and British law.

Comment: @Venture2099 I agree that the question would probably get better answers at [law.SE], but it doesn't seem to be actually off topic here.

Comment: *Wouldn't it be against the Human Rights of said migrants if they do restrict free-movement?* That assumes that the freedom to move around, especially across borders, is part of "human rights". I don't think you have established that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you go follow to the [1] footnote from your link, you get:

> Freedom of movement within a country encompasses both the right to travel freely within the territory of the State and the right to relocate oneself and to choose one's place of residence"

Note the `within a country` and how it talks about `the State` and not `any State`.

Basically, it means that you can:

- move anywhere in your country (for example, you are not forced to live near a farming field so you are left with no recourse but to farm that land for the landlord<sup>1</sup>).
- move to another country that accepts you with the security that your own country will not deny you the possibility of travel.
- move back to the country you are a citizen of whenever you want.

It does not mean that other countries have any obligation at all of accepting you<sup>2</sup> if they do not want to.

In fact, the Wikipedia article explains all of that in a rather clear way in its very first section.

---

About the Theresa May article, it does not mean what you say.

Once the UK exits the EU, all of the EU nationals residing in the UK will no longer have the automatic right of residence/work in the UK, as EU treaty obligations will no longer apply.

May declaration means that she is planning to negotiate that EU citizens residing in the UK will keep its residence/work rights if the EU also keeps the residence/work rights of UK residents in the EU. But that she wants such a deal to include only EU citizens living the UK before article 50 is triggered, and not those that arrive later.

---

<sup>1</sup> As happened with serfs.

<sup>2</sup> Asylum seekers and refugees are covered by other international laws.